How to create a data entry box in excel that would navigate me to a specific sheet in my excel workbook?
I run a pool league and every player has their own separate sheet where their performance is entered.
Instead of using excels menu option (a bit bulky, scrolling through 100 players takes time) I would like to insert a box on every sheet where I can enter a players number and it would change the sheet to the appropriate player.
I'm using free 365, no VBA. Is this possible?

Assuming your Excel file has a sheet named "Player345", you can use =HYPERLINK(CELL("address",INDIRECT(C24&"!A1")),"Click me to go to "&C24) to create a hyperlink that is dependent on the cell where you input a player name.
Formula break down:
You input player name in C24.
=CELL("address",INDIRECT(C24&"!A1")) is to get the address of cell A1 in sheet "Player345"
=HYPERLINK(CELL("address",INDIRECT(C24&"!A1")),"Click me to go to "&C24) then create a clickable hyperlink for that address.
Below is a screenshot to show how it is supposed to work.


Yes I know of this.
I need a data entry box that will basically just move to the appropriate sheet when player number is entered...players are not in particular order so your way would just create another menu I'd have to scroll through

I think you can create a tab, called ContentIndex, like this: https://imgur.com/a/kwjtawF, then in this tab, use =HYPERLINK("[Book2]"&G4&"!$A$1",G4) to create a link that will lead you to the sheet you specified. (G4 is the cell in which you input sheetname, or player name). then in each sheet for each player, use this to go back to the content index tab. =HYPERLINK("[Book2]ContentIndex!$A$1","ContentIndex")

In short, what you want to do is very similar to creating a clickable content index on pdfs or kindles etc.

The tab thing may be helpful I will try but it seems like just another "menu". I have a "master sheet" with a table that has player number and name. The whole workbook feeds off of it. I just want to create a box I can ebter 354 in and it goes to that player. Much easier and faster than finding a name in a list 100 people long and I expect it to grow.

You can make the hyperlink dependent on cell, where you input the player number.  Perhaps it is better if I add some screenshots in the answer post.

Yes rachel I think you have it...maybe just a box to put a number in then click GO and it opens the sheet...In short I do not want to refer to a sheet I need to open it. Just need to know how to make the link dependant

I added a screenshot and some comments on the hyperlink formula
